# disconnect client's socket with socket.id in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i created an array which contains our information about socket and sessions and nicknames like  below

```
 myarray ==   [
        {sessionId: '12345', nickname: 'timmay!', socketIds: [1, 2, 3]},
        {sessionId: '23456', nickname: 'pete', socketIds: [4, 5, 6]}
    ]
```

now i want to disconnect socket.id number 1 and 2 because i want a user just have 1 socket for 1 browser.
for example if user with nickname timmy open our chat with one tab of his browser we have  `socketIds: [1]` then if he open another tab we create another socket for him with id 2,now we have 2 id for one client.
is there anyway to disconnect id number 1 with socket.id?

some code like this for instance?

```
socket.disconnect(socket.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delete io.sockets.sockets[myarray[index].sessionId];
```